# What does it mean to be subscribed to click.lg?

Tags: jquery

I'm looking at a piece of code that I'm trying to understand. From my understanding there is an anonymous function that will be called when you click on the the element `$slide`. However, what is `.lg` after the click keyword? I've never seen this syntax before.

```
_this.$slide.on('click.lg', function() {
  _this.$el.trigger('onSlideClick.lg');
});
```

Comment: The `.lg` is a namespace on the `onSideClick` event. Here's a couple of articles about what it is and why it's useful: https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/ & https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/

Comment: Thank you, i appreciate it!